# Detect When the Canvas is Done Drawing - onload - onchange - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

Here is HTML and Code that draws an image into a canvas, after a user has used a file picker.

### HTML

```
<form class='frmUpload'>
  <input name="picOneUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="picUpload(this.files[0])" >
</form>

<button onclick='fncSaveAsJPG()'>Convert Img To JPEG</button>
<canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="266"></canvas>
<img id='imgTwoForJPG' src="">
```

### Script

```
<script>

window.picUpload = function(frmData) {
  console.log("picUpload ran: " + frmData);

    var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
    console.log("cnvs: " + cnvs);
    var ctx=cnvs.getContext("2d");
    cnvs.style.border="1px solid #c3c3c3";

    var img = new Image;

    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(frmData);

    console.log('img: ' + img);

    img.onload = function() {
      var picWidth = this.width;
      var picHeight = this.height;
      var wdthHghtRatio = picHeight/picWidth;
      console.log('picWidth: ' + Number(picWidth));
      console.log('picHeight: ' + Number(picHeight));
      console.log('wdthHghtRatio: ' + wdthHghtRatio);

      if (Number(picWidth) > 400) {
        var newHeight = Math.round(Number(400) * wdthHghtRatio);
      } else {
        return false;
      };

        document.getElementById('cnvsForFormat').height = newHeight;
        console.log('width: ' + picWidth + " h: " + picHeight);
        console.log('width: 400  h: ' + newHeight);
        //You must change the width and height settings in order to decrease the image size, but
        //it needs to be proportional to the original dimensions.
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 400, newHeight);
    };

    cnvs.onload = function () {
        console.log('Onload Canvas 2 Ran');
    };
 };

cnvsForFormat.onload = function () {
    console.log('Onload Canvas Ran');
};

</script>
```

I've tried attaching the `.onload()` method to various elements and put the code in various places without any luck.  How to I get some code to run with the `<canvas>` element is done with the `drawImage` event?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put whatever code you want after the `drawImage` call? Unless I'm missing something

Comment: I've tried that, and some code runs out of sequence.  It takes some time for the `drawImage()` method to draw data to the canvas.  In the meantime, javascript seems to continue to the next lines, running some code asynchronously.  This can cause code to actually run before the drawImage is done.

Comment: @Jnatalzia is correct.  If you have any code that relies on drawImage being complete then put that code after drawImage in the onload function.  The behavior you mention is standard behavior.  When you load an image the browser will immediately execute the code after .src and will execute the .onload code only after the image has fully loaded.

Comment: Your right.  Sorry about that. Thank you.